# Cannot to convert text-box text to list - WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, list, textbox

I'm trying to convert textBox.text to a list,
it gives me an error saying ***CS0029* Cannot implicitly convert type'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'**

The Main Class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace Making_A_Language
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow: Window
    {
        string filePath = @"D:\programs\Csharp\Making_A_Language\Making_A_Language\Code\Main.fysn";
        List<string> lines = new List<string>();
        List<string> TxtLines = new List<string>();
        string text;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            lines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath).ToList();

        }

        private void Btn_Save_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            text = TxtBox_Code.Text;
            TxtLines = text.ToList(); // <-- error is thrown here
            foreach (String txtLine in TxtLines)
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

The Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="Making_A_Language.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Making_A_Language"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="800" Width="1500" ResizeMode="CanMinimize" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" Background="#FF011D40">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox x:Name="TxtBox_Code" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="669" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="// Insert Code" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1474" Margin="10,92,0,0" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" FontFamily="Segoe UI Light" FontSize="24" Background="#FF002451" Foreground="#FF00FF17"/>
        <Button x:Name="Btn_RunCode" Content="▷" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="543,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="227" Height="72" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Background="#FF002451" Foreground="#FF00FF17" FontFamily="Segoe UI Light" FontSize="36" Style="{StaticResource RoundButton}"/>
        <Label Content="Code" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="77" Width="296" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" FontSize="48" FontFamily="Segoe UI Light" Foreground="#FF00FF18"/>
        <Button x:Name="Btn_Save" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="311,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="227" Height="72" Style="{StaticResource RoundButton}" FontFamily="Segoe UI Light" FontSize="24" Foreground="#FF00FF18" Click="Btn_Save_Click"/>
        <Button x:Name="Btn_DeleteAll" Content="️" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="775,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="227" Height="72" Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=RoundButton}" FontFamily="Segoe UI Light" FontSize="24" Foreground="#FF00FF18"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Im getting the error at `TxtLines = text.ToList();`
The buttons in the XAML have a custom style on them, tell me if you need the App.xaml,
If you need more context just tell me.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What are you trying to do with the Text property.

Comment: @bolkay I'm trying to write the text in the textbox to a file

Comment: If so, why are you trying to convert to a list? Just use the file class. `File.WriteAllText(string path, string text)`.

Comment: @bolkay I'll try

Comment: I tried this ```private void Btn_Save_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            File.WriteAllLines(filePath, TxtBox_Code.Text.ToList()); //<-- error here 
            lines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath).ToList();
        }``` but It gives me this error : **CS1503 Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<char>' to 'string[]**

Comment: Remove all those code. Just do  `File.WrtieAllText(filepath, text);`

Comment: even if I remove it it still gives me the error

Comment: @bolkay's solution should work just fine. Remove all the code in    Btn_Save_Click and use     File.WriteAllText(filepath, text);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you are trying to convert a multi-line string in a TextBox to List of strings. 
what you are doing doesnt work because the ToList() method as an extension of the String class will give you the characters in the string. In such a case, the string is actually an IEnumerable. See the output from the code below.

```
public static void Main()
    {
        string x="abcd";
        List <char> myChars = x.ToList();
        foreach (char c in myChars)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(c);
        }

    }
/*output
a
b
c
d
*/
```

If I am right, and you actually have new line characters in your TextBox, then what you want to do is simply split your strings using the newline character as the separator.

```
string [] myStrings = textBox.Text.Split('\n');
foreach (string str in myStrings) { /*do stuff here*/}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me

Answer (score 3):

You just can easily use .Split

Solution :

```
TxtLines.AddRange(TxtBox_Code.Text.Replace("\r", "").Split('\n'));
```